# Why Does 'SELECT count()' Return a Value of 'Array'?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add pagination to my MySQL results page. My goal at the moment is is to divide the number of results in the column (`$items_number`) by 10 since I want 10 results per page (`$per_page = 10`).

I had to convert `$items` into an array since it could not be read as a string, so now I have `$items_number = mysqli_fetch_row($items)`;

When I echo this in my code to see the number of items in a column, I get a message that says:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/ikb2014/public_html/test/classic_cars/pag_test.php on line 46
```

But it also STILL returns a value that says 'Array'. How can I get the value to report the number of items in the column instead of the word 'Array'?

Code:

```
<?php
require_once("./includes/database_connection.php");

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $per_page = 10;
    $query = "SELECT productCode, productName, productLine, productScale, productVendor, productDescription, buyPrice FROM products WHERE `productLine` = 'Classic Cars'";
                $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

    $query_count = "SELECT count(productLine) FROM products WHERE `productLine` = 'Classic Cars'";
    $items = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_count)
                or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
    $items_number = mysqli_fetch_row($items);


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="classic_cars.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        require_once("./includes/navigation.php");
    ?>


    <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $product_code = $row['productCode'];
            $product_name = $row['productName'];
            $product_line = $row['productLine'];
            $product_vendor = $row['productVendor'];
            $product_description = $row['productDescription'];
            $buy_price = $row['buyPrice'];

                echo "<tr>
                <td><p>$product_name</p></td>
                <td><p>$items_number</p></td>
                </tr>";

        } // end while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

    ?>


    <?php
        require_once("./includes/footer.php");
    ?>      
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From php documentation:

> mysqli_result::fetch_row -- mysqli_fetch_row — Get a result row as an
>   enumerated array
>
> > Fetches one row of data from the result set and returns it as an
> >     enumerated array, where each column is stored in an array offset
> >     starting from 0 (zero)

I will post 2 solutions for your problem:
First is to use

> mysqli_fetch_row

with COUNT function(like in your code):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($items);
$items_number = $row[0];
```

Second is to drop the COUNT FUNCTION and use

> mysqli_num_rows

like this

```
$query_count = "SELECT productLine FROM products WHERE `productLine` = 'Classic Cars'";
$items = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_count)
                or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
$items_number = mysqli_num_rows($items);
```

Comment: The count is being done via the SQL `count` function so only 1 row will be returned.

Comment: Aha, didn't even see that first query. Yea, with `$result` makes more sense.

Comment: The second query seems to be identical to the first (the condtions / no `LIMIT`), so it is not needed. Though I am not sure if this is really what the OP intends to do...

Comment: mysqli_fetch_row returns an array. So in your case,if you want to use the COUNT function you need to get the row containing the number or rows in a variable like this 
`$row = mysqli_fetch_row($items);
$items_number = $row[0];`
Then you can go with `$pages = ceil( $items_number / $per_page );`

Comment: Thank you, accessing just one of the array values worked. Can you move your last comment to your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I edited the answer and explained how to solve the problem in two ways.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do

```
SELECT count(productLine) as productcount FROM products WHERE `productLine` = 'Classic Cars'
```

So the key will be `productcount` in your array. Then

```
echo "<tr>
                <td><p>$product_name</p></td>
                <td><p>" . $items_number['productcount'] . "</p></td>
                </tr>";
```

to display it. That number is always going to be the same though, is that what you want?

Oh, also use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` for that. So `$items_number = mysqli_fetch_assoc($items);`

I think you in your current implementation

```
echo "<tr>
                <td><p>$product_name</p></td>
                <td><p>" . $items_number[0] . "</p></td>
                </tr>";
```

would work. I prefer using assigned names though incase a new column is added to the query or removed. Your `0` will always be the first column.

Links:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
SELECT count(productLine) FROM products WHERE `productLine` = 'Classic Cars'
```

to

```
SELECT count(*) FROM products WHERE `productLine` = 'Classic Cars'
```